# Embedding multiple elements in React component

Tags: reactjs, render

Getting error while embedding multiple elements in React component's return statement

Error is:

```
Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <textarea>
```

Have a look at my `render()` function

```
  render() {
    return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          Name:
          <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}> 
          <textarea/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </>
    );
  }
```

I am new to React and have already looked at similar questions. Please guide me.

Comment: change textarea like this <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a typo.Please change textarea jsx to following:

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}> 
</textarea>
// change
- <textarea />
+ </textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was banging my head for an hour for this.

Answer (score 0):

Closing tag of textarea should be `</textarea>` instead of `<textarea/>`